# Ways of Chaging Global Colors in Flutter

Tags: flutter

For styling reasons I created a class with N static variables that return Material Colors. However now I need to change these colors depending on the active theme (light or dark). I save the theme state using a provider. How can I do this?

Here's some of my colors class:

```
class ThemeColors {
  static const Color primary = Color.fromRGBO(25, 155, 241, 1);
  static const Color secondaryFontColor = Color.fromRGBO(100, 100, 100, 1);
  static const Color primaryFontColor = Colors.black;
  static const Color whiteFontColor = Colors.white;
  static const Color disabledFontColor = Colors.grey;
  static const Color backGroundColor = Color.fromRGBO(245, 245, 245, 1);
  static const Color greenFontColor = Color.fromRGBO(46, 158, 0, 1);
  static const Color whiteBackGroundColor = Colors.white;
  static const Color blackBackGroundColor = Colors.black;
  //Toast Colors
  static const Color successToastMessage = Color.fromRGBO(218, 255, 226, 1);
  static const Color warningToastMessage = Color.fromRGBO(255, 236, 199, 1);
  static const Color errorToastMessage = Color.fromRGBO(255, 157, 136, 1);

  //Notice Colors
  static const Color noticeBadWeather = Color.fromRGBO(41, 41, 41, 1);
  static const Color noticeUrgent = Color.fromRGBO(199, 31, 46, 1);
  static const Color noticeImportant = Color.fromRGBO(252, 192, 78, 1);
  static const Color noticeRegular = Color.fromRGBO(115, 161, 184, 1);
}
```

I want the variable to represent a different Color depending on the theme state. I also save the theme state inside the sharedpreferences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following things for that

Firstly create your theme class like below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

    class ThemeColor {
      static Color primary = Color.fromRGBO(25, 155, 241, 1);
  static Color secondaryFontColor = Color.fromRGBO(100, 100, 100, 1);
  .... //List all your colors for light theme and don't use const for them


      ThemeData themeData(bool isDarkTheme) {
        return isDarkTheme ? darkThemeData() : lightThemeData();
      }
    
    
      ThemeData darkThemeData() {
       //here you can change color for dark theme
        primary = Colors.white;
        secondaryFontColor = Colors.black;

        return ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'lexend',
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColor: blueSwatch,
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: customBlack),
          bottomAppBarTheme: const BottomAppBarTheme(color: customBlack),
          ........
        );
      }
    
      ThemeData lightThemeData() {
       //here you can change color for light theme
        primary = Colors.black;
        secondaryFontColor = Colors.white;
        return ThemeData(
          primaryColor: blueSwatch,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: blueSwatch.shade500),
          ......
        );
      }
    }
```

Call this method like below in Material App

```
MaterialApp(
    .....
     theme: Styles().themeData(/*PASS YOUR THEME VARIABLE HERE*/)
)
```

Comment: Humm I see. But that leaves me restricted to the variables available by themeData, correct? If you take a look at my variables, they are really customized... I need something like a rule that would overtake the value inside each variable depending on the current theme...

Comment: Actually, no you can create your custom variable but you need to change the value of that variable in `ThemeData lightThemeData()` or `ThemeData darkThemeData()` And you can call them like `ThemeColor.primary` or any variable name after `ThemeColor`